# .htaccess not working properly

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I changed .htacess file as below.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)product-list.php(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) www.example.com/swimming-pool/product-list\.php$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)product-info.php(.*)
RewriteRule (.*)\?(.*)$ www.example.com/swimming-pool/product\-info\.php$2 [R=301,L]
```

i just need that when i request for

`http://www.example.com/product-info.php?Applepc.html` should be redirected to

`http://www.example.com/swimming-pool/product-info.php?Applepc.html`

Output is getting like this in URL field:-

> www.example.com/swimming-pool/product-list.phpswimming-pool/product-list.phpswimming-pool/product-list.phpswimming-pool/product-list.phpswimming-pool/product-list.phpswimming-pool/product-list.phpswimming-pool/product-list.phpswimming-pool/product-list.phpswimming-pool/product-list.phpswimming-pool/product-list.phpswimming-pool/product-list.phpswimming-pool/product-list.phpswimming-pool/product-list.phpswimming-pool/product-list.phpswimming-pool/product-list.phpswimming-pool/product-list.phpswimming-pool/product-list.phpswimming-pool/product-list.phpswimming-pool/product-list.phpswimming-pool/product-list.phpproduct-list.php?Flowers-pg1-cid38.html

Please tell me where i am mistaking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you don't mention what is the purpose of the other rule with `product-list.php`, it is included in this rule-set.

You may try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (product-list|product-info)\.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$  swimming-pool/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Redirects permanently any URL like this one

`http://www.example.com/product-info.php?query` or

`http://www.example.com/product-list.php?query`

To

`http://www.example.com/swimming-pool/product-info.php?query` or

`http://www.example.com/swimming-pool/product-list.php?query`

It seems the problem with the actual rules is they are generating a loop.